# Redirecting /page.html to /page doesn't work inside subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect from `/page.html` to `/page` inside of a subdirectory, but it doesn't work.

- **What I do:** `http://example.com/subdirectory/page.html`
- **What I get:** `http://example.com/page`
- **What I want:** `http://example.com/subdirectory/page`

**.htacces file:**

```
RewriteEngine On

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for `.html` hiding in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

- Thanks